# Enable rotation lock by default in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, display-rotation, tablet-mode

I have a 2-in-1 Windows 10 computer, which can be either in laptop mode or tablet mode. Whenever I switch from laptop mode to tablet mode by turning the keyboard from in front of the screen to behind the screen, the rotation lock is always deactivated by default, even if it was on last time I was in tablet mode:

[image]

("Surplatteläge" means "tablet mode" and "rotationslås" means "rotation lock")

In tablet mode, I can enable the rotation lock, but then if I switch to laptop mode and back to tablet mode, rotation lock is disabled again. I would like the rotation lock to be on by default, so that I don't have to switch it on manually every time I enter tablet mode.

In the Settings app in System > Display, I found a Rotation lock setting which can be switched on or off, but that does exactly the same thing as the one in the action center, so it's always switched off whenever I enter the tablet mode, no matter how it was last time I was in tablet mode.

After searching on the internet, I found that there is a registry key for the rotation lock in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AutoRotation`. The `Enable` key is set to `0` if rotation lock is enabled (and auto rotation is disabled) and `1` if rotation lock is disabled (and auto rotation is enabled). I tried setting `Enable` to `0` to enable rotation lock, but each time I entered tablet mode from laptop mode it gets automatically set to `1` regardless of its previous value. I also tried changing the values of the other keys in there, setting `LastOrientation` to `1` instead of `0`, `SensorPresent` to `0` instead of `1`, `SlateEnable` to `0` instead of `1` and `NonPreserve\LastAutoRequest` to `1` instead of `0`, but none of that worked, it still automatically turns off rotation lock whenever I enter tablet mode.

How can I do so that the rotation lock doesn't automatically get disabled each time I enter tablet mode? I would like it to either remember if rotation lock was enabled or disabled last time I was in tablet mode, or just enable it automatically each time I enter tablet mode.