# Laptop Autorotate Cannot be Disabled

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, asus-laptop, rotate

I'm having an issue where I can’t disable the autorotate feature of my laptop. The display rotates from my preferred landscape view to the undesirable portrait view whenever I physically tilt the laptop past a certain point. I want this behavior completely turned off; I do not care for the rotation and I do not care for the tablet mode.

My laptop is an ASUS Q324UAK model running Windows 10 Home 64-bit.

Things I’ve tried that have been unsuccessful:

1. changing the value of the rotation lock option in the action center
2. setting the option for tablet mode to "don’t ask me and don’t switch"

A question similar to mine has been asked here [Enable rotation lock by default in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1325601/enable-rotation-lock-by-default-in-windows-10) but does not have any answers or comments.

I would be fine with changing registry values if it will fix the problem, but I tried what the OP suggested from the above question, and indeed the laptop still autorotates regardless of the registry edits.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. I only ever want to type and use my laptop as a computer, not a tablet and I don't want it to autorotate if I am moving to a different room or something. Finally, as I was in the display settings, I physically lifted my computer and turned it sideways and rotated the screen to portrait, and then hit the screen lock because it wasn't grayed out anymore. Then after I locked it, I chose to do landscape from portrait mode in the settings. Voila! It locked on the landscape mode and when I tip my laptop upside down or sideways it doesn't auto rotate on me anymore. It is so nice to have it stop doing that to me. ( also not sure if this makes a difference, but my laptop is also in the "don't ask, don't switch" option in the table mode settings and start "in desktop" mode as well.)

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following four way to lock screen rotation.

1: Turn On or Off Screen Rotation Lock using Keyboard Shortcut

2: Turn On or Off Screen Rotation Lock in Action Center

3: Turn On or Off Screen Rotation Lock in Settings

4: Turn On or Off Screen Rotation Lock using a REG file

For details we can refer this article: [How to Turn On or Off Screen Rotation Lock in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/104641-turn-off-screen-rotation-lock-windows-10-a.html)

If all the above does not work, I have seen the method but never try it.

• Go to **Device Manager**

• **Sensors**

• Disable **Invensense Sensor Collection**

[image]

In addition, some tablets have a button that allows you to quickly disable the auto-rotate function. We’ll need to check our manual to see if one of the buttons is meant for that function.

Comment: Hi Daisy, thank you for your answer. Steps 1-4 I have already tried, as described in my question and the linked answer. As far as the device manager screenshot, unfortunately I do not have the "InvenSense Sensor Collection" device listed there, so I might be out of luck. Additionally, I should make clear that I am having this issue on a laptop, not a tablet. The laptop does have a tablet mode, but it is still a laptop.