# I want to disable non-laptop features on my HP Pavilion

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, touchpad

I recently got an HP Pavilion, and all the "tablet mode" and touchscreen and autorotation settings are driving me up the wall.

I've already scoured the internet for solutions, I've turned off tablet mode, locked my laptop in landscape mode, changed the settings to "never put me in tablet mode", done everything I can think of, and nothing has helped.

But whenever the laptop gets tilted even the littlest bit to the side, the keyboard and touchpad automatically disable, as if the laptop is still automatically going into tablet mode, or some other touch-friendly mode.

I absolutely hate the touchscreen and all these other settings, and I just want to use my laptop as a plain old laptop.

Is there some way to disable all these bells and whistles and just have my laptop be a mouse-and-keyboard-only device?

Below are screenshots of the altered settings, so you can see that I've disabled all the settings I possibly can.

Tablet Settings:

[image: Tablet Settings]

Advanced Tablet Settings:

[image: Advanced Tablet Settings]

Comment: Have you contacted HP Support? They may have an update that will assist you.

Comment: Along with the tablet settings you already have set, have you attempted "Rotation Lock?" Find it in the Notification sidebar, in the Action Center. If you don't see the option, right click on the action bar buttons, and hit Edit and then Add to place the option in the Action Center buttons.  https://www.howtogeek.com/356809/how-to-disable-screen-auto-rotation-in-windows-10/ If any trouble with that, check this post out: https://superuser.com/questions/1347018/laptop-autorotate-cannot-be-disabled/1347447#1347447

Comment: Already did rotation lock. Now my laptop doesnt rotate the display, but anytime i turn it on its side, the keyboard and trackpad automatically shut off to "optimize" it for touchscreen mode. This is the type of behavior I'm trying to disable; I want my keyboard and trackpad to permanently be enabled regarless of what I do.